# How to switch between two different schemas in airflow dag?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I am struggling with something that looks very simple, but I don't know how to do that. we have 2 different schemas in our PRE env. How can I switch between 2 schemas in airflow? Imagine that I have only one dag .The same scenario in bash is to execute .sh with the env param (either mstr_new, mstr_pre) manually.

```
 ./script.sh env
```

Now to implement the same thing in Airflow, how we are going to specify what schema has to be executed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer to that in Airflow Best Practices:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#staging-environment